# is there any way to don't have to check every state between 2 numbers in batch?

Tags: batch-file

i was creating a rock paper siscors game in batch, i finisced and i wanted to "clean it", becouse it checked every possible combination between the 3 numbers rappresenting rock paper siscors, but i don't know what to do

at first i tried, instead of checking every equal number, i used the "equ" operator, but after that i didn't know what to do, i tried once by making the bigger number the winner, and checked if they were a 0 (paper) and 2 (rock) to make rock weaker than paper on the same "if" function, but the terminal just crashed.
i don't know how to do it somwhere else and then check after, i started using batch yesterday, so i dont know praticaly anything.
also if i did any error while typing correct me becouse english is not my first language

```
@echo off
color f
cls
echo welcome to rock paper siscors
:LOOP
echo 0=(paper) 1=(siscors) 2=(rock)
set /p input= select one of the 3:
set /a cpu=%random% %%3
if %input% GTR 2 (echo don't type values bìigger than 2!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)
if %cpu% equ 0 if %input% equ 1 (echo you win!)
if %cpu% equ 0 if %input% equ 2 (echo you lose!)
if %cpu% equ 1 if %input% equ 0 (echo you lose!)
if %cpu% equ 1 if %input% equ 2 (echo you win!)
if %cpu% equ 2 if %input% equ 0 (echo you win!)
if %cpu% equ 2 if %input% equ 1 (echo you lose!)
if %cpu% equ %input% (echo parity!)
if %cpu% equ 0 (echo the cpu selected paper)
if %cpu% equ 1 (echo the cpu selected siscors)
if %cpu% equ 2 (echo the cpu selected rock)
goto :LOOP
```

Answer (score 3):

Mmm.. These are my thoughs...

Scissors 1 win to Paper 0. Rock 2 win to Scissors 1; but Rock 2 should lose vs Paper. This means that Paper=0 should become Paper=3 IF the opponent is Rock 2. That is:

```
cpu += (!cpu) * !(input-2) * 3
```

We will do an extensive use of `!` (*Boolean NOT*) operator, that returns a 1 if its operand is zero, and returns a zero in any other case. In this way, `!cpu` is 1 if cpu is Paper and is zero in any other case (scissors or rock).

In the same way `(input-2)` is zero only when input is rock, so `!(input-2)` returns *one* only when input is rock (and zero in any other case).

This means that `(!cpu) * !(input-2)` gives 1 when cpu is Paper AND input is Rock (and 0 in any other case). If you multiply this value times 3 `(!cpu) * !(input-2) * 3` *and* add such a value to cpu: `cpu += (!cpu) * !(input-2) * 3` *then* this expression will convert cpu from Paper=0 to Paper=3 when input is Rock. Ta-Da!  **`:)`**

We must apply the same treatment to input when it is Paper and cpu is Rock, that is:

```
set /A cpu += (!cpu) * !(input-2) * 3
set /A input += (!input) * !(cpu-2) * 3
```

There is no way that *both* above expressions be executed *on the same data*, so it is not necessary to insert any IF to prevent to execute one or the other expression.

Also, it is simpler to get the user input via `choice` command that directly gives a 1..3 result, so we subtract 1 from its returned ERRORLEVEL in order to manage our standard values: 0=Paper, 1=Scissors and 2=Rock:

```
set /A "cpu=%random% %% 3"
choice /C PSR /N /M "Select [P]aper, [S]cissors or [R]ock: "
set /A "input=%errorlevel% - 1"
set /A "cpu += (!cpu) * !(input-2) * 3"
set /A "input += (!input) * !(cpu-2) * 3"
if %cpu% gtr %input% (echo you lose) else ...
```

But the `SET /A` command can execute several operations separated by comma, so above 4 expressions could be given in *a single* SET /A command. Also, we can get the name of each item via an [array of names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) that can directly give the desired element in a single operation. Here it is the whole thing:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the "items" array
set "item[0]=Paper" & set "item[1]=Scissors" & set "item[2]=Rock" & set "item[3]=Paper"

:LOOP
    choice /C PSR /N /M "Select [P]aper, [S]cissors or [R]ock: "
    set /A "input=%errorlevel%-1, cpu=%random% %% 3, cpu+=(^!cpu)*^!(input-2)*3, input+=(^!input)*^!(cpu-2)*3"
    if %cpu% gtr %input% (
       echo you lose
    ) else if %cpu% equ %input% (
       echo parity
    ) else (
       echo you win
    )
    echo cpu selected !item[%cpu%]!
    choice /M "Play again? "
    echo/
if not errorlevel 2 goto LOOP
```

---

We could also eliminate the IF's commands used to identify the winner via the following trick. If we analyse the possible values of the expression `input - cpu`, we'll realize that if the result is 2 or 1, you win; if it is 0, is draw; and if it is -1 or -2, you lose. We could *directly* use these values to define a "result" array with 5 elements this way:

```
rem Define the "results" array
set "result[2]=you win"
set "result[1]=you win"
set "result[0]=parity"
set "result[-1]=you lose"
set "result[-2]=you lose"

. . .

set /A "res=input-cpu"
echo !result[%res%]!
```

However, we could diminish the "result" array to just 3 elements if we use the "Sign" function that returns 1, 0 or -1 for positive, zero or negative values, respectively:

```
set /A "res=input-cpu, res=(res>>31|1)*!!res"
```

Here it is the final version:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the "items" array
set "item[0]=Paper" & set "item[1]=Scissors" & set "item[2]=Rock" & set "item[3]=Paper"

rem Define the "results" array
set "result[1]=you win" & set "result[0]=parity" & set "result[-1]=you lose"

:LOOP
    choice /C PSR /N /M "Select [P]aper, [S]cissors or [R]ock: "
    set /A "input=%errorlevel%-1, cpu=%random% %% 3, cpu+=(^!cpu)*^!(input-2)*3, input+=(^!input)*^!(cpu-2)*3, res=input-cpu, res=(res>>31|1)*^!^!res""
    echo !result[%res%]!
    echo cpu selected !item[%cpu%]!
    choice /M "Play again? "
    echo/
if not errorlevel 2 goto LOOP
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
:again
SET /a cpu=(%RANDOM% %% 3) + 1
SET "result="
SET "player="
choice /c rpsq /m "[R]ock [P]aper [S]cissors [Q]uit "
(
 FOR %%e IN (1:Rock 2:Paper 3:Scissors 21 32 13) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=:" %%b IN ("%%e") DO (
  IF %errorlevel%==%%b SET "player=%%c" 
  IF %cpu%==%%b SET "cpu=%%c" 
  IF %errorlevel%%cpu%==%%b SET "result=beats" 
 )
IF %cpu%==%ERRORLEVEL% SET "result=Draws with"
IF NOT DEFINED result SET "result=Loses to"
)
IF DEFINED player ECHO %player% %result% %cpu%&GOTO again
ECHO Quit?
ECHO Scaredy cat!

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's my version.

First set `cpu` to a random number 1 to 3
Then use `choice` to set `errorlevel` to 1(Rock) 2(Paper) 3(Scissors) or 4(Quit)
Then notice that the next statement (`for...%%e...`) is parenthesised, so is parsed as a single block
`%%e` is set to the value of each of the strings in its parentheses in turn
`%%b` and `%%c` are set to the string before and after the `:` delimiter in the string `%%e`
If `%%b` = `errorlevel` as set by the `choice`, set `player` to R/P/S
Ditto `cpu` from the value set by the `set /a`
set `result` to `beats` if {player choice number}{cpu choice number} is mentioned on the `for %%e` list
If both player and cpu choices are identical, set `result` to `draws with`
if `result` is still not assigned, it's neither a win nor a draw, so it's a loss
If `player` wasn't set in the loop, then `errorlevel` set by the `choice` must be `4` for `Quit`, otherwise output the three strings and go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not a direct fix for your reported problem, here's an rewritten example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to study, *and which may better suit your purpose*:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Color 0F
Echo Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors

:LOOP
Set /A "Opponent=(%RANDOM% %% 3) + 2, Opponent *= Opponent"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C RPS /N /M "[R]ock, [P]aper, or [S]cissors?"
Set /A "Result=Opponent - %ErrorLevel%"
Set "Opponent=Paper"
If %Result% Lss 4 Set "Opponent=Rock"
If %Result% Gtr 8 Set "Opponent=Scissors"
For %%G In (15 6 2) Do If %Result% Equ %%G Set /P "=You WIN: " 0<NUL
For %%G In (14 8 1) Do If %Result% Equ %%G Set /P "=You LOSE: " 0<NUL
For %%G In (13 7 3) Do If %Result% Equ %%G Set /P "=DRAW: " 0<NUL
Echo Opponent chose %Opponent%
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Would you like to play again"
If Not ErrorLevel 2 Echo(& GoTo LOOP
```